# What's the default login for the Windows XP IE6 VPC image supplied by Micosoft?

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

I downloaded the Microsoft-supplied [Virtual PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC) image for Windows XP / [Internet Explorer 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6) testing from http://modern.ie and tried to login using the documented credentials of IEUser / Passw0rd! [(referenced in the MS supplied release notes)](https://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/virtualmachine_instructions_2013-07-22.pdf)

This does not work. What are the correct default login credentials?

Comment: Note that the documented credentials IEUser / Passw0rd! do work on many of the Virtual PC images.

Answer (score 121):

The credentials listed in the MS release notes will not work.

Instead, use `Administrator` / `Passw0rd!` to login (notice `Passw0rd!` **is** the default password, as specified in the VMs' wallpapers).

It may warn you that `IEUser` is already logged in if this is the first time runnning the image.

Comment: In the version distributed now, at least in the Windows 10 + Edge version, the user is `IEUser` and the password is (still) `Passw0rd!`

Answer (score 8):

The password on my copy of Windows XP VM was `Password1`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to click on "Disable Integration Features" in Virtual PC -> Tools menu. This should allow you to log on on the machine without typing the password (since no password is set for IEUser)